# running WCF behind loadbalancer where LB connection to IIS is http and client connection to LB is HTTPS

Tags: wcf, https, web-config, load-balancing

The setup looks something like this:

service client --httpS--> loadbalancer --http--> IIS hosting WCF

I receive this error:

The message with To 'https://MyDomain.com/Service.svc' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.

I suspect this has something to do with the fact that the service is only setup to run http. There is no certificate on the server as this is handled at the loadbalancer.

I am aware of this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971842 (FIX: URIs in a WCF WSDL document refer to inaccessible internal instances)

We are running .Net 4.

I can provide more information, just not sure what would be helpful at the moment.

Thanks

Comment: Short term we're adding a cert to the IIS server and so will be SSL internal from LB to IIS, which seems weird, but it works for now. We still think there should be a configuration setup that would make this work without running SSL between IIS and LB. Hopefully someone can answser this. The WCF config documentation seems hopelessly thin.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem (though it's a slightly different error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have authentication using username password then WCF basichttpbinding would not allow this, to get around this there is [clearusernamebinding](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2008/11/introducing-wcf-clearusernamebinding.html) which would solve your issue.

If you dont have any authentication then the general basichttpbinding would be enough for the above scenario. Just configure your WCF service with basichttpbinding and just make sure that the LB sends the request to the web server as http.

Comment: We are currently using wsHttpBinding. I'll try it with basic and see how it goes.